# How to make chocolate fondant?

Tags: dessert

I am willing to add a 2-3mm thick chocolate fondant coating to my home made biscuits. I believe this is very common, but I have no idea how to do this.

The fondant should be pretty solid (not liquid or fluffy), opaque and should not melt at room temperature.

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Question is off topic. See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#questions on recipes.

Comment: But I believe my question relates to "Cooking & food preparation methods" :)

Comment: Eh, I'm on the fence with this one. We prefer it when questions show some preliminary effort, but speaking as someone who's made a lot of pastries, fondant isn't really a "recipe" any more so than pastry cream or caramelized sugar; it's just corn syrup, icing sugar, and whatever other flavours you want (i.e. chocolate). Let's see how this plays out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really substitute marshmallows in that recipe. I have had some luck with the following procedure:

1. Get a good quality chocolate of the flavour you would like to use. Do not try chocolates with 70% cocoa solids or more. They are good for some things, but not for this.
2. Melt it in a double boiler. Do not make the chocolate boil or heat it directly (some can do that but most people end up with burned chocolate). Remove it from the heat.
3. Fold in 2 spoons of glycose syrup (for regular nonmilky chocolate) and mix fast. Let it cool and when it gets close to room temperature, put it in the fridge. For darker chocolates, use a bit more glucose and less for lighter chocolates.

Comment: It sounds pretty nice. Will definitely try it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try making Marshmallow fondant but substituting some confectioners sugar for cocoa powder.  You can find tons of recipes for marshmallow fondant online.  I personally do not like to use shortening, so I used [this one](http://candy.about.com/od/fondantcandyrecipes/r/mm_fondant.htm).

You can add in some cocoa powder instead of using all confectioners sugar.  Worked fantastic for me.

You just roll it out as usual.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have marshmallows in my country. By what should I replace the marshmallows?